# Pulling data from Google Cal xml

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm running into an error when trying to pull some data from Google Cal using PHP. Here is the code:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$ns= $feed->getNameSpaces(true);

foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) {
    $eventdetail = $entry->children($ns["gd"]);
    $when_atr = $eventdetail->when[0]->attributes();

    $title = $entry->title;
    echo "<div class='eventTitle'>".$title . "</div>";

    $where = $eventdetail->where[0]->attributes();
    echo "<div class='eventLocation'>" . $where . "</div>" . '<br />';

    $start = new DateTime($when_atr['startTime']);
    echo "<div class='eventTime'>".$start->format('D F jS, g:ia') . " to ";    

    $end = new DateTime($when_atr['endTime']);
    echo $end->format('g:ia')."</div>" . '<br />' ; 
}
```

The titles work just fine, but for both the "when" and "where" I'm running into problems with the code `when[0]->attributes();` and `where[0]->attributes();`.

The error I get is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: check whether `when[0]` is actually an object before trying to call a method on it. Same for the where, obviously.